# Wrong hostname resolution in Local network

Tags: linux, ip, dhcp, nfs, hostname

**context**

I was  trying in vain to map drives from my NAS to my PC via NFS when I figured out that my PC hostname was not resolved with the proper IP address from my NAS or any other devices connected to the local network managed by an old Lynksys router.

Here is my current [setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPL0M.png)

**current behavior**

When pinging my PC, I end up with an address which is not 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.81 instead)

```
root@ix2-2:/ $ ping jb-Nitro-AN515-52 
PING jb-Nitro-AN515-52 (192.168.1.81): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ix2-2 (192.168.1.103): Destination Host Unreachable
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst Data
 4  5  00 5400 0000   0 0040  40  01 a0b6 192.168.1.103  192.168.1.81 


pi@raspberrypi3 ~ $ ping jb-Nitro-AN515-52
PING jb-Nitro-AN515-52 (192.168.1.81) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.102 (192.168.1.102) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I [unplugged the internet cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5axK.png) from the lynksys router, I have unknown host/Temporary failure in name resolution

```
root@ix2-2:/ $ ping jb-Nitro-AN515-52
ping: unknown host

pi@raspberrypi3 ~ $ ping jb-Nitro-AN515-52
ping: jb-Nitro-AN515-52: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**expected behavior**

If I ping jb-Nitro-AN515-52 from ix2-2 or raspberrypi3, I should be able to ping with address  192.168.1.101

Answer (score 0):

Lame answer but only things I found so far, forcing the IP in **/etc/hosts** on ix2-2 and raspberrypi3....

```
192.168.1.101 jb-Nitro-AN515-52
```